# Can I rename columns for query results in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query where some columns being returned are results of a sum() function, and the column is named "sum(price)" but I want the column name to be "total". Is there a way to do that in SQLite?

Query:

```
SELECT name, sum(price) FROM trades WHERE trader_id = 7 group by symbol;
```

Current output:

```
+------------+-------------+
|    name    | sum(shares) |
+--------------------------+
|   netflix  |       523.26|
+--------------------------+
|   tesla    |      9276.06|
+------------+-------------+
```

Intended output:

```
+------------+-------------+
|    name    |    total    |
+--------------------------+
|   netflix  |       523.26|
+--------------------------+
|   tesla    |      9276.06|
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `as total` does exactly what you are looking for. It creates an [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

```
SELECT name, sum(price) as total FROM trades WHERE trader_id = 7 group by symbol;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use column aliases:

```
SELECT name, sum(price) total FROM trades WHERE trader_id = 7 group by symbol;
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't known that one can leave `as` away. I tested it on mariadb an sqlite3. Does it works on other sqlengines too?